# LAContext evaluatePolicy does not always prompt user

Tags: ios, touch-id

In my iOS 7 iPad app LAContext:evaluatePolicy sometimes returns SUCCESS without prompting the user to touch the ID button. And the Apple docs say “Evaluating a policy MAY involve prompting the user…”.

My authentication policy is set to LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, the only choice I see. Why wouldn’t this prompt the user to touch the ID button every time I call evaluatePolicy? Is there a way I can require this behavior?

Comment: Do you mind marking my answer as the correct one?

Comment: Sorry, your answer did not solve my situation.

Answer (score 19):

I have experienced a similar problem.
It is possible that you are declaring a global variable something like

```
let authenticationContext = LAContext()
```

and then use authenticationContext within your class methods and functions.

I have started declaring the constant in each function I use it like

```
func someAuthFunc() {
let authenticationContext = LAContext()
...
```

and my problem was solved.
I was asked each time I requested evaluateForContext ...

I hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: The documentation suggests this should not happen, but it definitely is happening:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1622329-touchidauthenticationallowablere

Auth0's SDK stores a private LAContext which makes this a bit problematic for users of that SDK 

Comment: This solved my problem as well.

Answer (score 4):

**For who have the same issue**

It just happens from iOS 13 and above. The solution is trying to call `evaluate` function twice like this:

```
let systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
// Trick here: Try to do a pre-evaluate
if systemVersion.compare("13.0", options: .numeric) != .orderedAscending {
    context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: "Authenticate to open the app", reply: { (_, _) in
         //Ignore callback here
     })
}

context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: "Authenticate to open the app", reply: { (success, error) in
    // Handle callback here
})
```

Tested and work well for all iOS 13.x.x versions so far.

Comment: I like your solution and can confirm it's working. It's fixed with iOS 13.2 - Can you adjust your code to only include 13.0 and 13.1? Is this correct? -> if systemVersion.compare("13.0", options: .numeric) != .orderedAscending && systemVersion.compare("13.1", options: .numeric) != .orderedDescending {...}

Comment: For the condition, if it works for iOS 13.0.x & 13.1.x and fixed from iOS 13.2.x, so the code should be: 
`if systemVersion.compare("13.0", options: .numeric) != .orderedAscending && systemVersion.compare("13.2", options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending {
      // 13.0 <= version < 13.2
}`
@Paul

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem after iOS13 update. Not a good workaround but calling evaluatePolicy twice solved the problem for me

```
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { _, _ in
            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { isSuccess, _ in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if isSuccess {
                        success()
                    } else {
                        fail(authError?.localizedDescription ?? "User did not authenticate successfully")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like it was fixed in 13.1.3

Comment: Can confirm this is still an issue in 13.1.3

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug on iOS 13, 13.1 and is planned to be fixed in 13.2. I'd suggest trying your code on the iOS 13.2 beta to see if it's any better.

source: [iOS 13 Touch ID Delay/Bug](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123623)

Comment: Still happening to me on 13.6